# how to run multiple queries via DOS batch file, which will create plsql packages

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, sqlplus

how to run multiple queries via DOS batch file, which will create plsql packages?

I'm that far:

This is my 'driver'

```
@Echo Off
sqlplus [login details] @C:\runPackages.sql 
EXIT
```

and in file runPackages.sql I have:

```
@C:\SqlPackage1.sql
@C:\SqlPackage2.sql
@C:\SqlPackage3.sql
```

Its seems, that this is working for simple Sql Queries, but its not creating packages...

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: How do you know it's not creating packages?  What does it do?  Do you get any error messages?  What happens if you run, say, `@C:\SqlPackage1.sql`manually in SQL*Plus instead of using that driver  script?

Comment: Well it gives me number... Just that. Like 69, or 6800. Don't know, what does that mean... When i press ENTER, new number appears with +1 value...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> "Well it gives me number... Just that. Like 69, or 6800. Don't know,
>   what does that mean."

What that means is you haven't terminated your CREATE PACKAGE scripts properly.  That is SQL*Plus's way off telling you it expects you to enter another line of code.  And that's why they don't run from the driver script either.

After the `end;` you need a new line and a slash to execute the statement.  Like this

```
create or replace package package1 as
....
end package1;
/
```

Finish off each CREATE statement with the slash and your scripts will run without further input.

The teaching from this is, we need to test our individual program units first before we integrate them at a higher level.